# Excel: Concatenate space separated Firstinitial Middleinitial LastName @email.address.com

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I am trying to figure out how to concatenate a users First initial, Middle initial, and Last name with an "@emailaddress.com". The user's whole name will be in a single cell, separated only by spaces.  I need to pull the first and middle initials along with the last name, concatenate them and add the email address extension, all in another cell.

Example:

Cell 1: John P Smith

Cell 2 (needs to be): jpsmith@emailaddress.com

Thanks All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following *UDF*:

```
Public Function MailMe(s As String) As String
    ary = Split(s, " ")
    MailMe = LCase(Left(ary(0), 1) & Left(ary(1), 1) & ary(2) & "@mailaddress.com")
End Function
```

[image]

However, to make this "click-able" use this in the worksheet cell:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & mailme(A1),mailme(A1))
```

Comment: Definitely the clean way to go about this.  Makes handling the middle name much easier as well if it's not a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming middle initials are always one letter, use this

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,1),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,1),MID(A1, FIND(" ", A1, FIND(" ", A1)+1)+1,256),"@emailaddress.com")
```

It basically works by getting the first letter from the left, the first letter after the first space, and anything past the second space and then adds @emailaddress.com. Change A1 to whatever cell your name is in and @emailaddress.com to the email address.

Comment: Additionally, put the entire thing in LOWER() to make it lower case if necessary. Currently it keeps the J/P/S capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that assumes there is only a single letter for the middle name.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
    LEFT(A1,1) & RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))
  ," ","")&"@emailaddress.com"
```

**How it works**

- Grabs the first letter with `LEFT`
- Finds the end of the first name and grabs the `RIGHT` of the text from there
- Replaces the spaces with nothing using `SUBSTITUTE`
- Tacks on the `@emailaddress` part

**Picture of ranges and results**

[image]